# Style ChoiceBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

How can you style a ChoiceBox in JavaFX with CSS? The only things I have found out is how to change the background and the text color.

```
// Background Color
.cb {
   -fx-background-color: #HEX;
}

// Text Color
.cb .label {
   -fx-text-fill
}
```

[image]

What I am still missing is the highlighting color when hovering the items and the background color of the dropdown list. Also the little arrow. Unfortunately I have found no documentation or anything that helps.

**EDIT:**

@James_D gave a great link to find out stylings: [Modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)

That way I figured out how to color the white background black.

```
.cb .context-menu {
   -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the highlighting color:

```
.cb .menu-item:focused {
  -fx-background-color: yellow ; /* for example */
}
```

The background color of the dropdown list:

```
.cb .context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: antiquewhite ;
}
```

For the arrow:

```
.cb {
  -fx-mark-color: green ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! can you tell me how to change the whole dropdown list? How that <tag> is called? And most importantly how did you know of which parts a ChoiceBox is made of?

Comment: Edited with background color of dropdown list. I figured it out from a combination of the [source code for the default style sheet, modena](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), and, for the background of the dropdown list a little bit of guesswork.